# Printing a simple rhombus pattern in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print this pattern in Python 3 (I'm a beginner):
[image: Rhombus image]

What i have tried :

```
n = 5

for x in range(1, (n+5) //2 + 1):
    for y in range( (n+5) //2 - x):
        print(" ", end = "")
    for z in range( (x*2)-1 ):
        print("*", end = "")
    print()

for x in range( (n+5)// 2 + 1, n + 5):
    for y in range(x - (n+5) //2):
        print(" ", end = "")
    for z in range( (n+5 - x) *2 - 1):
        print("*", end = "")
    print()
```

But the result is like this:
[image: Rhombus]

How can I make the middle hollow like in the image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates of the points on the hollow rhombus satisfies `|x|+|y|==m` (where `m = n-1`). Therefore, you could use

```
In [29]: m = n-1; print('\n'.join([''.join(['*' if abs(row)+abs(col)==m else ' ' for col in range(-m,m+1)]) for row in range(-m,m+1)]))
    *    
   * *   
  *   *  
 *     * 
*       *
 *     * 
  *   *  
   * *   
    *
```

or, equivalently, but without [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
n = 5
m = n-1
for row in range(-m, m+1):
    for col in range(-m, m+1):
        if abs(row) + abs(col) == m:
            c = '*'
        else:
            c = ' '
        print(c, end='')
    print()
```

To make the solid rhombus, simply change the condition to `abs(row) + abs(col) <= m`.

Answer (score 0):

With recursion:

```
def print_stars(i,n):
    if i:
        print( ' '*(n-i-1)  + '*' + ' '*(2*i-1) + '*')
    else:
        print( ' '*(n-1)  + '*')

# recursive
def r(n, i=0):
    print_stars(i,n) # up
    if i<n-1:
        r(n, i+1) # recurse
        print_stars(i,n) # down

# start
r(5)
```

prints:

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*       *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple python code without using functions

```
rows = 7

for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, rows - i + 1):
        print(end = ' ')
    for k in range(1, 2 * i):
        if k == 1 or k == i * 2 - 1:
            print('*', end = '')
        else:
            print(' ', end = '')
    print()

for i in range(rows - 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(1, rows - i + 1):
        print(' ', end = '')
    for k in range(1, 2 * i):
        if k == 1 or k == i * 2 - 1:
            print('*', end = '')
        else:
            print(' ', end = '')
     print()
```

Output:

```
      *
     * *
    *   *
   *     *
  *       *
 *         *
*           *
 *         *
  *       *
   *     *
    *   *
     * *
      *
```

Answer (score 0):

How to make a "Hollow Diamond In Python 3.10"
You can use this code here:
[my personal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxKBb.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).